# What do these 2 icons mean in Killzone 2?

Tags: killzone-2

When a Skirmish match ends in Killzone 2, stats are shown. I’m pretty sure I know what most of the icons mean, but what do the 2 with ??? mean?

And why does Tremethick have -1 for one of his stats?

[image: Scoreboard with all the icons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The pentagon** is objective points. In Body Count it's points for kills, in Assassination it's for killing the target or surviving as the target, Capture and Hold it's for killing people in the capture zones, etc.

**The slashed O** means penalty points (team kills + suicides)

Comment: I discovered that I cannot kill a teammate, even when they are Mortally Wounded. I tried shotguns to the face, grenade launchers at point blank, emptying a whole clip point blank, not possible.

Comment: What is the difference between Objective Points and Mission Points? I asked thta question here (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347995/killzone-2-objective-points-vs-mission-points) if you want to answer it. 

Comment: Did a small update as suicides also count in penalty points. Team kills are activated and deactivated based on multiple things - More discussion here https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/928377-killzone-2/48459140

Comment: answered you other question where each column is described. Good Luck!