# Killzone 2: Objective Points vs. Mission Points?

Tags: terminology, killzone-2

In Killzone 2 Skirmishes, there are [Objective Points and Mission Points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347982/what-do-these-2-icons-mean-in-killzone-2/347989#347989). What is the difference between the two? Or, what is the definition of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective Points = Mission points.

What you are referring to is **Total Points** (The last column in the stats). Those take into consideration:
 + Mission points
 + Kill Points (No of kills * multiplier, based on headshot or other )
 - Penalties

So you have:

-> Deaths

-> Penalties (team kills + suicides)

-> Objective points (surviving an Assassination, making an Assasination, blowing up an S&D...)

-> Opponents killed

-> Total points (opponents killed with multipliers  and objectives are taken into consideration - penalties)

This was also discussed here:

https://www.neoseeker.com/forums/32245/t1423204-confused-with-score-system-multiplayer/